# Keep old value checkbox laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 9.x project, and when I submit the form and an error occurs, I have managed to keep the already inserted value of the text fields, but I would like the checkboxes to keep their value as well.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="abono_tasa" value="{{ isset($vado->abono_tasa) ? ($vado->abono_tasa==1 ? 'checked': '') : '' }}" id="abono_tasa">
```

I would like to control this.

Comment: Yes, you can use `old` method. What does `old('abono_tasa')` give you? See [more](https://www.google.com/search?q=old+in+laravel+site:stackoverflow.com&sca_esv=562487504&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN1055IN1055&sxsrf=AB5stBjlmBYg8bOSGfEsxA5TPJOle3vzhA:1693819416796&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwiWhZuF0ZCBAxX94jgGHZONDisQrQIoBHoECA4QBQ&biw=1536&bih=739&dpr=1.25) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you can keep the old value of a checkbox input when a form is submitted and there are validation errors, using the `old` function in the Blade templates.

When you're rendering the form, you can use the `old` function to set the checkbox to its previous value if there are validation errors. Here's an example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="abono_tasa" id="abono_tasa" value="1" @if(old('abono_tasa')) checked @endif />
```

For convenience, you may use the @checked directive to easily indicate if a given HTML checkbox input is "checked". This directive will echo checked if the provided condition evaluates to true:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="abono_tasa" id="abono_tasa" value="1" @checked(old('abono_tasa')) />
```

Thank you.
(Please, consider making this answer the selected answer if the solution works for you).

Comment: Fyi, there is a @checked directive in Blade. See: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#additional-attributes

Comment: @iH8 Thank you. I'll now update my answer to include the new directive.

Answer (score 0):

### For variable-based default value

In below, if `$myDefault` is set to `true`, it equals checking the check-box by default.

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="myCheckedValue"
       name="myField"
       @if((!old() && $myDefault) || old('myField') == 'myCheckedValue') checked="checked" @endif />
```

### Always checked by default

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="on"
       name="myField"
       @if(!old() || old('myField') == 'on') checked="checked" @endif />
```

### Always un-checked by default

Below does not need "`!old()`" workaround.

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="on"
       name="myField"
       @if(old('myField') == 'on') checked="checked" @endif />
```

> Related Laracast: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-set-old-value-for-checkbox-input-using-blade?page=1&replyId=771230